# Deploying to Heroku Error. Giving logs

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

http://gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com/

App is deployed from C9 (mysql databases, NOT postgresql) and here are my logs. Unsure of what the issue is.

> 4.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:41:31.091593+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=cc817f43-c067-47f5-b488-0e96f5207c2c fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:41:31.891130+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=1943dc6d-721a-4761-a393-52b4816ef387 fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:41:32.045544+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=963024c6-60e0-4540-896b-5de8d09c081b fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:41:32.351885+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=d594a1d8-379d-4d95-a54d-48eca9788237 fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:41:32.531014+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=848521cb-af78-4884-af8e-a62bf1624bab fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:43:44.753508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=ab2215ad-aad7-479e-a9d5-a0db08791950 fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:43:44.910248+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=79216544-8c50-4561-839a-be2cbb234a77 fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:44:12+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
>   2014-11-16T17:44:20+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app
>   2014-11-16T17:45:54.324695+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=6f5c17fd-5c75-482e-851e-b0e18291eb6d fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:45:54.609157+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=312743fb-a8a1-4d72-8ab6-d91a28cd3f27 fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:45:55.378930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=24822512-b401-4281-9aa4-d7d0de596f22 fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:45:55.720652+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=gentle-wildwood-7307.herokuapp.com request_id=cc8e0da3-ccf9-4389-9b2d-7ccf1bdc7e85 fwd="64.236.208.24" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>   2014-11-16T17:46:26.595187+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sportsdude.reese@gmail.com
>   2014-11-16T17:46:30.757912+00:00 heroku[run.5329]: Awaiting client
>   2014-11-16T17:46:30.806568+00:00 heroku[run.5329]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
>   2014-11-16T17:46:30.994709+00:00 heroku[run.5329]: State changed from starting to up
>   2014-11-16T17:46:35.021047+00:00 heroku[run.5329]: Process exited with status 1
>   2014-11-16T17:46:35.027007+00:00 heroku[run.5329]: State changed from up to complete
>   2014-11-16T17:47:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
>   2014-11-16T17:47:54+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Ruby app

Answer (score 0):

It seems that problem is with migrations.